Can we show $I_s(\mu) \lesssim_{\mu} I_t(\mu)$ when $0 < s < t$? When is $\frac{I_s(\mu)}{I_t(\mu)} \le 1$?
Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\Bbb R^n$, with compact support $\operatorname{spt} \mu$. I'd like to show that if $0 < s < t$, then $I_s(\mu) \lesssim I_t(\mu)$. In particular, I'd like to know when $I_s(\mu) \le \alpha I_t(\mu)$ for $\alpha \le 1$. Here, $I_s(\mu)$ is the $s$-dimensional Riesz energy of $\mu$, defined by $$I_s(\mu) := \int\int |x-y|^{-s}\, d\mu(x)\, d\mu(y).$$

Suppose $0 < s < t$, and define $D(\mu) = \operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{spt} \mu) < \infty$.
\begin{align*}
I_s(\mu) &= \int\int |x-y|^{-s}\, d\mu(x)\, d\mu(y)\\
&= (D(\mu))^{-s} \int\int \left(\frac{D(\mu)}{|x-y|}\right)^{s}\, d\mu(x)\, d\mu(y)\\
&\le (D(\mu))^{-s} \int\int \left(\frac{D(\mu)}{|x-y|}\right)^{t}\, d\mu(x)\, d\mu(y)\\
&= (D(\mu))^{t-s} \int\int |x-y|^{-t}\, d\mu(x)\, d\mu(y) = (D(\mu))^{t-s} I_t(\mu).
\end{align*}
Question $1$: The bound above shows $I_s(\mu) \lesssim_{s,t,\mu} I_t(\mu)$. Can we get better bounds, and is it possible to establish $I_s(\mu) \lesssim_{\mu} I_t(\mu)$?
I'm also interested in another aspect of this computation, and I'm asking this in the same post since it's closely related.
Question $2$: When is $\frac{I_s(\mu)}{I_t(\mu)} \le 1$?
Given the computation above, if $(D(\mu))^{t-s} \le 1$, then $\frac{I_s(\mu)}{I_t(\mu)} \le 1$. Since $s < t$, we have $(D(\mu))^{t-s} \le 1$ if and only if $D(\mu) \le 1$.
Thanks for any insights! The questions are somewhat open-ended, so I do not expect very concrete answers.
